# Can I have CPU limits for a node?

Tags: kubernetes, limit

In the past I observed nodes unresponsiveness, master didn't seem to communicate with those nodes under heavy loads, when my pods are overloaded. So I set CPU limits for those pods as equal to CPU requests. Since then nodes are healthy even when pods are overloaded and wait to scale out.

However, CPU usages of pods are not even. It will be useful if I set CPU limits more than CPU requests. Say, my pod have 4 worker processes with 1 CPU request and limit (I know 4 CPU requests and limits are desirable for 4 processes, but it means x4 cost). If I give 2 or more CPU limits, they can be burstable, but I fear unstable nodes again.

If I can set node CPU limits shared with pods in a node I will be happy.
I know node CPU allocatable and capacity, but I think even capacity doesn't limit the total of pod CPU usage. or I'm wrong with this?

Answer (score 0):

If you can run the relevant pods in a separate namespace altogether you could use *ResourceQuotas*

*ReesourceQuota* provides constraints that limit aggregate resource consumption per namespace. It can limit the quantity of objects that can be created in a namespace by type, as well as the total amount of compute resources that may be consumed by resources in that namespace.

The *ResourceQuota* parameter *limits.cpu* might be just what you are looking for. Across all pods in a non-terminal state in the given namespace, the sum of CPU limits cannot exceed this value.

You can read more about ResourceQuota here:
https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/policy/resource-quotas/

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I don't want to limit total CPU usages in a namespace. I do want to limit total CPU usage in a node.

Comment: I feel what you are trying to achieve is counter to what Kubernetes is built for. Kubernetes is built for using clusters as a whole, abstracting away individual machines from the view. Pin-pointing a machine and making specific changes to it will only complicate things.
Ideally, you should figure out a way to make the CPU Usage of the pods nearly equal to each other by load-balancing etc. and set the limits at pod level (that's what Kubernetes is built for). 

Avoid spending time looking for workarounds for designs that go against the platform's underlying philosophy.

Comment: I don' want to complicate things. I just want to pretect nodes from overloaded pods. Yes, as I described in my question set pod CPU limits under CPU requests achive this, but I think total CPU hard limit to protect nodes should be done by default IMO. Anyway thanks for your opinion.